# Create a Model by hand

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I need to be able to access the value "_CustomUserID" from other controllers within the application. I  created a class but not sure how to return the value to be used by the Controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.DirectoryServices;

namespace myfirstapplication.Models
{
public static class ActiveDirectory
{
 public static UserPrincipal GetCustomID()
    {
      DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
      de.Path = "LDAP://10.1.1.1:389";
      DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
      deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CustomUserID"); 
      deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

      deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" + Membership.GetUser().UserName + "))";
      SearchResult results = deSearch.FindOne();

      string _CustomUserID = (String)results.Properties["CustomUserID"][0];
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method signature into string like this :

```
public static string GetCustomID()

{
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
      de.Path = "LDAP://10.1.1.1:389";
      DirectorySearcher deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
      deSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CustomUserID"); 
      deSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

      deSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=user)(SAMAccountName=" + Membership.GetUser().UserName + "))";
      SearchResult results = deSearch.FindOne();

    Return (String)results.Properties["CustomUserID"][0];

}

//then in your controller all u have to say is :
string _customerId = ActiveDirectory.GetCustomID();
```

thanks hope this helps!

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thank you kindly.

Comment: Another related question. How do I pass multiple properties? Say I also have 
(String)results.Properties["CustomUserID"][0]
(String)results.Properties["displayName"][0]
(String)results.Properties["PostalAddress"][0]
Thank you

Comment: you can change the Method Signature to List<string> ReturnCustomIds, then keep adding these to the List<String> that your going to return!
public static List<string> GetCustomIDs()

{
List<String> _returnList=new List<String>();
......same code
  _returnList.Add((String)results.Properties["CustomUserID"][0]);
  _returnList.Add((String)results.Properties["CustomUserID"][1])
return _returnList;
}

//then in your controller all u have to say is :
List<string> _customerIdsss = ActiveDirectory.GetCustomID();

Comment: My Controller seem happy with no errors. However, when I pass it to the View like this `List<string> mylist=GetBannerIDfromAD.GetCustomID();  
            ViewBag.myList = mylist;
            return View(mylist);` I get this message. 
 _"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String], but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable"_ Obviously is a type mismatch but can't figure out how display it.

Comment: try using return View(mylist.ToList());

Comment: I tried your suggestion but my View() still returning the same error. _System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]_ How do I display data?